# Expression giving multiple plots of a function, where each plot varies according to the value for a certain parameter

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

How can I plot multiple plots for M = 10, 20, 50?

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1}, {-1, -1 <= x <= 0}}];

M = 50;

c = Parallelize[
   Table[(2*n + 1)/2 Integrate[f[x]*LegendreP[n, x], {x, -1, 1}], {n, 
     1, M}]];
```

I would like to plot for each M at once.

```
Plot[{Sum[c[[n]]*LegendreP[n, x], {n, 1, M}], f[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Thick, Blue}}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, I may not get exactly what you want to do, but if I do the only thing you need to do is create Table for multiple M and `Join` this Table with `f[x]` and use this new list as your first argument for `Plot`.

Comment: @Wizard wont that overlay them on the same plot?  If so, I am looking to have them on different plots not on one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way that straigthforwardly makes a table of plots:

```
Table[Plot[{Sum[c[[n]]*LegendreP[n, x], {n, 1, M}], f[x]}, {x, -1, 1},
     PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Thick, Blue}}, GridLines -> Automatic], {M, {10, 20, 50}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can each graph be in its own output window?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "window" but you can arrange them at your convenience. For instance, add `//TableForm` and the three are vertically oriented. Or use `Grid` or `GraphicsRow` or `GraphicsColumn`. Each of these has many display options (for spacing and other things).

Comment: @dustin Perhaps `Table[CreatePalette@Plot[...]]` or `CreateDocument` is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Many ways to do this. This is another variation of Bill's answer using `Do`, `Reap`, `Sow` , `Partition` and `Grid`

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1}, {-1, -1 <= x <= 0}}];
m = 50;
c = Parallelize[Table[(2*n + 1)/2 Integrate[f[x]*LegendreP[n, x],{x, -1, 1}],{n,1,m}]];

r = Last@Reap@Do[Sow@Plot[{Sum[c[[n]]*LegendreP[n, x], {n, 1, m}], 
       f[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Thick, Blue}}, GridLines -> Automatic,
       AxesLabel -> {x, Row[{"n=", m}]},ImagePadding -> 30], {m, 1, 50, 2}];

Grid[Partition[r[[1, All]], 5], Frame -> All, Spacings ->{1, 1},FrameStyle->LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can each graph be in its own output window?